# firebase cloud function deploy glob error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, glob

When deploying my cloud functions using the command `firebase deploy` I am getting this error for all of my functions:

```
!  functions[deleteGame-DeleteGameFunction(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:11:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
```

This is my index.js file [(I got it from here)](https://codeburst.io/organizing-your-firebase-cloud-functions-67dc17b3b0da):

```
'use strict';
/** EXPORT ALL FUNCTIONS
 *
 *   Loads all `.f.js` files
 *   Exports a cloud function matching the file name
 *   Author: David King
 *   Edited: Tarik Huber
 *   Based on this thread:
 *     https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/170
 */
const glob = require("glob");
const camelCase = require("camelcase");
const files = glob.sync('./**/*.f.js', { cwd: __dirname, ignore: 
'./node_modules/**'});
for(let f=0,fl=files.length; f<fl; f++){
  const file = files[f];
  const functionName = camelCase(file.slice(0, -5).split('/').join('_')); // 
Strip off '.f.js'
  if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === 
functionName) {
    exports[functionName] = require(file);
  }
}
```

This index.js file is a way to organize your firebase cloud functions that I found on https://postmarkapp.com/blog/sending-transactional-emails-via-firebase-and-cloud-functions that got it from https://codeburst.io/organizing-your-firebase-cloud-functions-67dc17b3b0da
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you need to install glob module too. like `npm install --save glob`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to run this from your functions directory:

```
npm install glob
```

And probably also

```
npm install camelcase
```

You can't `require` a module without first installing it into your project like this.

Comment: Do I also need to include glob and camelcase as dependencies in the package.json file? Thank you

Comment: Just run the commands from your functions directory.  They will be added to your package.json.  It might be worthwhile to read up on how node projects work - this is pretty standard stuff.

Comment: I ran the commands, but nothing got added to the package.json file

Comment: Did you run it from your functions directory?

Comment: That was probably my mistake, thanks and is there any node.js materials that you would recommend reading so that a simple mistake like this one doesn't happen again?

Comment: The documentation for npm is a good place to start for learning about how packages work. https://docs.npmjs.com/

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson